# How to get mac address or uuid from mobile device PDA based on JavaScript?

Tags: uuid, mac-address

I am going to make a mobile web page that calls URL in a web method from a Chrome browser on a PDA PM85. The weird thing is to get the mac address or uuid of the mobile device from javascript, but I don't know how.

Comment: you cannot access the mac address from a web browser context.

Comment: So can't you get uuid?